# R: how to assign column name to a variable and using it in function

Tags: r

I have a dataframe called test1 with some data, for example:

```
    name  address
1   xxx1    x
2   xxx2    y
3   xxx3    z
```

I have some code

```
new.function = function(dataframe, colname){
   print(dataframe$colname[1])
}

#call function
new.function(test1, "name1")
```

I want it print out xxx1 because the function does the same as test1$name[1] but it failed. I just thinking about how to assign a column name to a variable so that it can be used in function more flexiable.

Comment: Read `help("[")`. It says that you can't use `$` like this and what you should use instead.

Comment: @Roland Found it. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you only want to assign the column name to a variable you can do :

```
variable <-names(test1)[1]
```

To print xx1 :

```
print((test1$name)[1])
```

You should take a look at dplyr to handle table easily